Is sharing code of a web scraping snippet allowed?
I made a script to extract the whole list of extensions from the Chrome Web Store (https://chromewebstore.google.com/). This script does not use authentication.
I didn't find anything related in their Terms of Service but I'm not used to read those documents: https://ssl.gstatic.com/chrome/webstore/intl/en/gallery_tos.html
Is it allowed to share this code publicly?
EDIT:

I understand from this question it depends on the TOS of the target hence my question
From there, I understand it is legal because the script do not need authentication ?
From there, I understand scrapping is prohibited from the TOS?

Well, with this contradictory information, I don't have my answer.

https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=web+scraping

@BlueDogRanch already searched.... And already seen you, posting the same comment... My question is not about the scrapping itself, neither selling the data, but only about publishing the code to do it (regarding the TOS of Google)

Google's TOS contains the following clause:

3.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) the Web Store by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) the Web Store through any automated means (including use of scripts, crawlers, or similar technologies) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Web Store website.

So anyone who uses your script would be violating the "through any automated means" provision.
It's not clear that the author of the script has violated any terms, though. I couldn't find any clause that prohibits reverse-engineering the Web Store, or aiding others who choose to violate clause 3.3.
However, if scraping the Web Store is considered copyright infringement, the provider of the tool might possibly be guilty of contributory infringement.
